# Should I Configure Babel Through .babelrc or WebPack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

In my react project, *webpack.config.js* brings in proposal-class properties like so:

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
        }
      },
    }
...
```

By including `@babel/proposal-class-properties` I'm able to remove the constructors from my React components, etc.

However, the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) shows `plugin-proposal-class-properties` in `.babelrc` as follows (and doesn't mention `webpack.config.js` at all):

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

whereas my `.babelrc` does not include any plugins at all:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "modules": false
    },
    "@babel/preset-env"]
  ]
}
```

Is there any effective difference between including the plugins (such as `proposal-class-properties`) in `webpack.config.js` as compared to putting them in `.babelrc`?

Comment: No. Whatever you define in webpack under `use` for babel, is combined with your `babelrc` configuration. My preference is to use `babelrc` for configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure babel through `.babelrc` or through the `babel-loader` configuration in webpack. **They both work exactly the same.**

However, I recommend only using `.babelrc` for configuring babel.
That way it can also work when you run your tests, which usually don't go through webpack and will therefore not have the webpack configuration for babel.

*.babelrc:*

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  "plugins": ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {'loose': true}]
}
```